# clickhouse approach for word frequency count on textual field

Tags: word-count, clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse table, where one of the fields contains a textual description (~300 words).

For example Reviews:

```
Rev_id    Place_id    Stars    Category    Text
1         12           3        Food       Nice food but a bad dirty place.
2         31           4        Sport      Not bad, they have everything.
3         55           1        Bar        Poor place,bad audience.
```

I'd like to make some word count analysis, such as general word frequency count (how many times each of the words has appeared) or top-K words per Category.

In the example:

```
word    count
bad     3
place   2
```

...
Is there a way to do it solely in ClickHouse without involving programming languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    arrayJoin(splitByChar(' ', replaceRegexpAll(x, '[.,]', ' '))) AS w,
    count()
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Nice food but a bad dirty place.' AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Not bad, they have everything.'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Poor place,bad audience.'
)
GROUP BY w
ORDER BY count() DESC

┌─w──────────┬─count()─┐
│            │       4 │
│ bad        │       3 │
│ place      │       2 │
│ have       │       1 │
│ Poor       │       1 │
│ food       │       1 │
│ Not        │       1 │
│ they       │       1 │
│ audience   │       1 │
│ Nice       │       1 │
│ but        │       1 │
│ dirty      │       1 │
│ a          │       1 │
│ everything │       1 │
└────────────┴─────────┘


SELECT CATEGORY, ....
GROUP BY CATEGORY, w
```

Answer (score 1):

If it applicable in your case I would consider using the [alphaTokens](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/functions/splitting_merging_functions/#alphatokens-s) as a more efficient one.

```sql
SELECT
    category,
    arrayJoin(arrayFilter(x -> NOT has(['a', 'the', 'but' /*.. exclude stopwords */], x), alphaTokens(text))) token,
    count() count
FROM
(
    /* test data */
    SELECT data.1 AS rev_id, data.2 AS place_id, data.3 AS stars, data.4 AS category, data.5 AS text
    FROM
    (
        SELECT arrayJoin([
          (1, 12, 3, 'Food', 'Nice      food but a bad dirty place.'), 
          (4, 12, 3, 'Food', ' the the the the good food   ..'), 
          (2, 31, 4, 'Sport', 'Not bad,,, they have everything.'), 
          (3, 55, 1, 'Bar', 'Poor place,bad audience..')]) AS data
    )
)
GROUP BY category, token
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 5;
/*
┌─category─┬─token────┬─count─┐
│ Food     │ food     │     2 │
│ Food     │ bad      │     1 │
│ Bar      │ audience │     1 │
│ Food     │ Nice     │     1 │
│ Bar      │ Poor     │     1 │
└──────────┴──────────┴───────┘
*/
```

Example of using [topK](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#topk-n-x):

```sql
SELECT
    category,
    arrayReduce('topK(3)', 
                arrayFilter(x -> (NOT has(['a', 'the', 'but' /*.. exclude stopwords */], x)), groupArrayArray(alphaTokens(text)))) AS result
FROM
(
    /* test data */
    SELECT data.1 AS rev_id, data.2 AS place_id, data.3 AS stars, data.4 AS category, data.5 AS text
    FROM
    (
        SELECT arrayJoin([
          (1, 12, 3, 'Food', 'Nice      food but a bad dirty place.'), 
          (4, 12, 3, 'Food', ' the the the the good food   ..'), 
          (2, 31, 4, 'Sport', 'Not bad,,, they have everything.'), 
          (3, 55, 1, 'Bar', 'Poor place,bad audience..')]) AS data
    )
)
GROUP BY category;
/* result
┌─category─┬─result─────────────────┐
│ Bar      │ ['Poor','place','bad'] │
│ Food     │ ['food','Nice','bad']  │
│ Sport    │ ['Not','bad','they']   │
└──────────┴────────────────────────┘
*/
```

ps: probably make sense to [lower](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/functions/string_functions/#lower-lcase) all strings/tokens before processing